# Amazone Alexa/Development Console - my changes don't deploy

Tags: console, alexa-skills-kit, developer-console

I'm using the developer console to learn Alexa skill development.

I started with the "Hello World".  Sure enough it works fine.  I can test it.  So, then I changed it to say "Greetings World", saved it, built it and was told all was good.

Yet, when I test I still get "Hello World".  Clearly I am missing a step, assuming 'deploy'.  But I can't see a link for that.

Answer (score 0):

**3 Ways**

1. **If you're using Alexa Hosted**
   Click on the Deploy Button

[image]

2. **If you're using [ask-cli](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/ask-cli-command-reference.html#generate-catalog-upload-url-subcommand)**
   use [ask deploy](https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/ask-cli-command-reference.html#deploy-command)

```
ask configure # first time running ask command
ask deploy # every time you want to deploy it
```

3. **You have a manual endpoint (define in the build menu > Endpoint)**

Make sure the code behind this endpoint is up to date (deploy your lambda or update your API)

Comment: Yep - that was it - I knew there had to be a deploy.  It was just that I use a chromebook and my screen was not wide enough to see the deploy button and I never thought to side-scroll